# self-contained javafx application fail to run in ubuntu : issue with GLIBCXX_3.4.21

Tags: java, ubuntu, javapackager, self-contained

- I built a small app using javafx ( very basic stuff )
- compile using javac : OK ( oracle jdk 1.8.0_201-b09 )
- crated the jar : OK : the jar works fine with java -jar
- packaged the app using javapackager

  > javapackager \
  >   -deploy \
  >    -daemon \
  >   -srcfiles $JAR_FILE:./lib/$LIB_JAR.jar \
  >   -outdir $DIST_FOLDER \
  >   -outfile dist \
  >   -native deb \
  >   -appclass com.myapp.client.gui.Main \
  >   -name "MyApp" \
  >   -title "MyApp" \
  >   -v
- run the generated deb installer ( same machine )
- go the the installed app under /opt/MyApp, and when I ran `MyApp` it just complains about `GLIBCXX_3.4.21` not found

I have tried all sort of apt fixes but nothing worked..

it's worth mentioning that this is all done in a fresh ubuntu desktop version running from a virtual machine. ( ubuntu 14.04.1 amd64 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with jdk8u181 or less. The provided launcher from the jdk (in lib/ant-javafx.jar -> ./com/oracle/tools/packager/linux/JavaAppLauncher ) doesn't have the same symbol tables. It looks like a bug in oracle's jdk compilation and distribution system.

```
$ objdump -T 181/./com/oracle/tools/packager/linux/JavaAppLauncher

181/./com/oracle/tools/packager/linux/JavaAppLauncher:     format de fichier elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSsaSEPKc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dirname
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSsC1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 printf
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSspLEPKc
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*    0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*    0000000000000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNKSs5c_strEv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _Znam
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __libc_start_main
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSsD1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlclose
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSsC1EPKcRKSaIcE
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 readlink
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSaIcED1Ev
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*    0000000000000000              __pthread_key_create
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZdaPv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlopen
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlsym
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 setlocale
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSaIcEC1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Resume
0000000000400a50      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  CXXABI_1.3  __gxx_personality_v0


$ objdump -T 191/./com/oracle/tools/packager/linux/JavaAppLauncher

191/./com/oracle/tools/packager/linux/JavaAppLauncher:     format de fichier elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dirname
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 printf
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*    0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _Znam
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __libc_start_main
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEpLEPKc
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlclose
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 readlink
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSaIcED1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZdaPv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlopen
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlsym
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE5c_strEv
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 setlocale
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1EPKcRKS3_
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 _ZNSaIcEC1Ev
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GCC_3.0     _Unwind_Resume
0000000000000000      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4.21 _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEaSEPKc
0000000000400be0      DF *UND*    0000000000000000  CXXABI_1.3  __gxx_personality_v0
```

Comment: thanks!
i will give this a try and see if it fixes it .
I have used jdk 10 to get around the issue.. but it was a pain since it is not LTS